# argmax result as a subtensor

Tags: numpy, theano

I want to use the argmax with kept dimensions as a subtensor. I have:

```
m, argm = T.max_and_argmax(a, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
```

And I want to set those values to zero in `a`. I.e. I need to use `T.set_subtensor`. To use that, I need to specify the subtensor `a_sub` of `a` at `argm` but I'm not exactly sure how that looks like. `a_sub = a[argm]` is wrong for multiple dimensions.

This should hold:

```
a_sub == T.max(a, axis=axis)
a_sub.shape == T.max(a, axis=axis).shape
```

In the end, I want to do:

```
a = T.set_subtensor(a_sub, 0)
```

My current solution:

```
idx = T.arange(a.shape[axis]).dimshuffle(['x'] * axis + [0] + ['x'] * (a.ndim - axis - 1))
a = T.switch(T.eq(idx, argm), 0, a)
```

However, `a_sub = a[T.eq(idx, argm)]` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Theano's [advanced indexing features](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing) which, unfortunately, differ from [numpy's advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Here's an example that does what you want.

**Update:** Now works with parametrized axis but note that `axis` cannot be symbolic.

```
import numpy

import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

theano.config.compute_test_value = 'raise'

axis = 2

x = tt.tensor3()
x.tag.test_value = numpy.array([[[3, 2, 6], [5, 1, 4]], [[2, 1, 6], [6, 1, 5]]],
                               dtype=theano.config.floatX)

# Identify the largest value in each row
x_argmax = tt.argmax(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True)

# Construct a row of indexes to the length of axis
indexes = tt.arange(x.shape[axis]).dimshuffle(
    *(['x' for dim1 in xrange(axis)] + [0] + ['x' for dim2 in xrange(x.ndim - axis - 1)]))

# Create a binary mask indicating where the maximum values appear
mask = tt.eq(indexes, x_argmax)

# Alter the original matrix only at the places where the maximum values appeared
x_prime = tt.set_subtensor(x[mask.nonzero()], 0)

print x_prime.tag.test_value
```

Comment: My `axis` is variable. Also `ndim` is variable (in my tests it's 3). How would it look like then?

Comment: @Albert updated the code but note axis cannot be symbolic.

Comment: Ah I see, I also missed `nonzero()`. I'm using `tt.switch(mask, 0, x)` now instead of `tt.set_subtensor(x[mask.nonzero()], 0)`. Do you know which would be faster?

Comment: I don't know but would also be interested in knowing. I would hope that the  optimizer is able to detect the equivalence and produce identical execution graphs.

Comment: Another follow-up question: What is the difference between `mask.nonzero()` and `argm`?

Comment: `x_argmax` is `array([[[2], [0]], [[2], [0]]], dtype=int64)` while `mask.nonzero()` is `(array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64),)`

Comment: `mask.nonzero()` should be `([array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]), array([2, 0, 2, 0])])`. I'm asking because I think it should be possible to construct something similar directly from `x_argmax`, shouldn't it?